# book shelf brackets

Tags: walls, shelving, brackets

20 years ago we put up bookshelves (still doing fine) and now wish to add some more shelving but I bought (without thinking) some single-track brackets from Loews and they are about a millimeter off and lack the edging found on the originals so they would not wobble when in position. Where do I look for older brackets?
Peter Loewer
Asheville, NC
28803

Comment: Perhaps a photo or two would help explain what you're asking.  I'm not at all clear on "new" vs. "old" bracket styles.

Comment: Take one of the older ones with you to the store in order to try and match them.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.